# How important is the website logo on a page?

Tags: html, seo

I have stopped to insert "img" tags for the logo of the page. Because its not an image that is part of the content, its a design element but its still a information I want to have control over. So I just write the title in a "a" element as display: block, overflow: hidden and I push the text out with some padding. I think thats a good solution for SEO because you are keeping control of how important the logo should be on a page.

But now my dilemma is starting. How important is the logo of a page?

"A list apart" puts the logo in a h1 element. But is the logo really that important? On article pages you have two H1 elements (the logo and the title of the article) Most of the sites just use a img balbal /a, but I don't like this solution. Because I just want to use img for images that are part of the content...

Its kinda philosophical question, I hope you can give me some input or some articles to read about that...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Think about it this way: "*How should a text-to-speach browser translates the page if a disabled person visit the site?*".

Do you want the text-to-speach to mention the logo as an image? If yes: the logo should be an img with a caption providing a textual description. If no: use whatever alternative to no have image as content.

Do you want to emphasize the importance the page title, the article time, and the logo?

I guess I would

- use an `img` for the logo (so that it's also printed, which is not always case if you use background image)
- provide a nice caption (with "`alt`" attribute) that describes the logo and the company
- have the page title be "`company - page title`"
- have the main title be `h1`.

I feel like it should also gives decent SEO results.

Answer (score 11):

For the homepage, the logo is a very important heading.

```
<h1><img src="/logo" alt="ACME inc."></h1>
```

…and it is an image that is part of the content, it isn't decorative or part of the background.

For other pages, it isn't.

```
<div><a href="/"><img src="/logo" alt="ACME inc."></a></div>
<h1>Products</h1>
```

Comment: Appart from the philosophy... why having <div><a><img> when you could have only a <a> displayed as block with a background image ?

Comment: I would so vote this up if you didn't have `<img>` tags instead of text.

Comment: Like David says, the logo is in fact part of the content and not just decorative, so I definitely agree that it's a valid use of the `img` element.

Comment: I'm not sure an image with an "alt" is as good as plain text, SEO-wise

Comment: I think you should definitely add the title as plain text as well, there's no use in using the <h1> apart from the semantics if you don't put text in it, at least not from a SEO point of view.

Comment: I consider providing a good experience to users to be a better approach then trying to game the moving target that is search engine indexing algorithms. As for the div, the logo usually belongs in a logical block of its own, and not inline with whatever follows it. CSS is there so you can style the right markup, not so you can just have less markup.

Comment: Alt text in an IMG is preferrable to image-replacement for a logo, according to Google's Matt Cutts. See http://www.youtube.com/user/GoogleWebmasterHelp#p/search/0/fBLvn_WkDJ4

Also, when linking to the page on Facebook, Facebook will pick up your logo if it's an IMG tag. If it uses CSS image-replacement it will not.

Lastly, I think it's more semantic to use an image for your logo.

Answer (score 3):

Your logo represents your brand identity.  It is the **ONE** thing you want your visitors to remember (if they like your site, that is).

I personally recommend always using a CSS image replacement technique for your logo in an `<h1>` tag because you want search engines to recognize this as your bread and butter.  You want to ensure you rank on the top for your company name.  This will help get you there.

```
h1#logo { height: LOGOHEIGHTpx; width: LOGOWIDTHpx; text-indent: -999em; overflow: hidden; background: transparent url('/path/to/logo.gif') 0 0 no-repeat; }
```

Comment: But how do you handle SEO? On a page with an article, the title of the page is more important, then to logo. A page is always about the content. The place where you find this content is secondary to me. I like the solution on David D. I would just not place IMG tags in h elements.

Comment: nothing wrong with an img inside a h1, but you should add the title itself as well

Comment: I think i a "h" shoud be text only. Does the title tag of the image take the same importance as it would if i would just write the title in the h tag? (for SEO or a Textnavigator?)

Answer (score 2):

I prefer putting the logo in an H1 and hide the name of the website. The logo is a big part of the website's identity but it's also often the "home" link... so it's important enough!

edit: CODE SNIPPET TIME!!

```
<h1><a href="/" id="logoLink">my company</a></h1>
```

with a background image on the link (and displayed block with a set width and height etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Q: -How important is the websitelogo on a page? 
A: -Very important! :)

Answer (score 1):

Speaking as an old search engine guy, the logo itself is not really what the page is about. I normally put it (img or text) in a styled div. The title of the specific purpose of the page is normally what you want to wrap in an H1. This is usually the same as the TITLE, although I normally tack on a " | SiteName.com" to the title so that the site name shows up clearly in the results listing.

Answer (score 1):

I always do this:

HTML:

```
<h1 id="logo"><a href="#">Company Name (with tagline, if any)</a></h1>
```

CSS:

```
#logo a {
  float:left;
  width: ...px;
  height: ...px;
  text-indent:-1000em;
  background: url(/path/to/image) no-repeat;
}
```

You can replace the H1 with H2, H3 etc.. on the inner pages, but I prefer keeping the header (and other sections) consistent as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is good practice to have your `<h1>` tags match (or contain) similar text to the `<title>` of the page. For this reason, I think the following pattern is a good one:

```
<title>Your Site Name Here</title>

...

<h1 id="logo">Your Site Name Here</h1>
```

And on other pages:

```
<title> Article Title Here  | Your Site Name Here</title>

...

<div id="logo"><a href="/">Your Site Name Here</a></div>

...

<h1>Article Title Here</h1>
```

Having the nested `<a>` tag in the `div#logo` allows you to have a different click area than logo display. For instance, if you have a wide drop shadow or other element that doesn't make sense to have clickable, the `a` could be smaller than the `div#logo` and help with that.

Answer (score 0):

10 years back when i first visited a new search engine i only saw a textbox and a logo on top that said 'google'.The web page was ordinary didnot have any a lot of html elements infact only a textbox and a logo, but i always remembered the page due to the logo and the excellent search results.
Logo is important man, very important

Comment: sure on the home page the logo is important. But once your search results are showing up. I think you care about the results it self and not the logo any more...

Comment: Very true, i fully agree with you.Its like buying a product, you select the product based on the product itself and the packaging.But later you use the product only .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the top of this page.  You can't go much of anywhere on this site without seeing the "stack overflow" logo up in the corner.

I'd say at least 90% (probably more!) of web sites I visit on a regular basis have a recurring logo.  Marketing is a sick and twisted thing, but if so many web sites are doing it, it's probably not too far wrong.

From a visual standpoint, a logo is crucial -- it is part of the identity of the page, and users will associate it with the content.  It's almost an imperceptible thing, but I know if I didn't see a logo at the top of a content page, it'd almost smack of unprofessional design to me!  It's a subtle thing.  Make sure the users know where they are and what they're looking at; form a psychological association.

Yes, search engine results are important, but that doesn't mean the logo is a throwaway.

Comment: yeah but i don't care about the visuals. I talk about the Information importance. If you visit a page with a text browser. How important is the name of the company/site compared to the content of the actual page?

Answer (score 0):

I used to do the same image-replacement thing, but I finally realised it was a waste of time. As long as a meaningful `alt` attribute is present, you should just have the image.

As for the appropriate markup: on the home page I have the logo as `h1` as it's the title of the page. On other pages I have it in a `p` and the actual title of the page is `h1`.

For example, home page is:

```
<div id="header">
  <h1><img src="logo.jpg" alt="HyperGlobalMegaCorp"></h1>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <h2>Welcome to the HyperGlobalMegaCorp website</h2>
</div>
```

whereas contact page is:

```
<div id="header">
  <p><img src="logo.jpg" alt="HyperGlobalMegaCorp"></p>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <h1>Contact HyperGlobalMegaCorp</h1>
</div>
```

...and that's HTML, not XHTML, before some zealot starts going on about closing the `img` elements ;-)

Comment: isn't the alt designated to describe the content of a image and title to to say what it actually is? Or do i understand something wrong? Or is it really only used to describe the picture in case the image cant me seen by the user?

Alt = corporate logo
Title = HyperGlobalMegaCorp

Comment: @david: `alt` is alternate content to be used when the image cannot be rendered: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/objects.html#adef-alt whereas `title` supplies "advisory information": http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/global.html#adef-title Generally speaking `title` is text of less significance (i.e. it doesn't matter if the user never actually sees or hears it), as evidenced by the fact that it is always optional, whereas `alt` is mandatory on `img` and `area` elements.

Answer (score 0):

I use the both logo image and text for improving SEO on my site

```
<h1 id="pageheading"><a href="http://mysite.com" title="site description">
<span>Site name</span><img src="mylogo.gif" alt="my brand" />
</a></h1>
```

then I used css for formatting display so visitor can see only my logo but SE can see the both that make double search result for 2 type of search `text` and `image`. The image which use searched  is the brand of your site, when visitor see your logo, they thought about your site, your products, services like as HP, IBM, DELL etc.... In other case you can make paragraph tag for more description about your site to focus some keywords in your site.
My language skill is not good but I still want to share to you some knowledge,  dont laugh me when I got mistake about grammar please :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your inputs, it helped me a lot. This is my conclusion of all your answers and my thoughts:

It depends on your programming style and personal philosophy how you implement your logo technically. Some are using IMGs inside H tags, some are hiding the content of what ever tag they used and are placing the logo as background image.

But i think i have got my answers:

Consider the website as a book or magazine. On the front cover you want to have the title of the book as most important element and maybe some headlines. But inside the media you gonna implement your book/magazine title into the header and maybe the footer.

In order to make this understandable for a text navigator or a search engine. I would now choose a h1 tag to place my logo on the main/home page. But on the other pages a simple IMG, A or whatever tag but H.

Please share your thoughts about my conclusion.