# css: insert to divs float right under each other within a parent div

Tags: css, html, css-float, vertical-alignment

I've used a solution from [Replacing H1 text with a logo image: best method for SEO and accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665037/replacing-h1-text-with-a-logo-image-best-method-for-seo-and-accessibility), but I need to insert two divs, each float right, under each other. I have some problems with that. How to fix that?

Please see the example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/QnFZT/1/ (**updated**)

Comment: Why are they inside your `<h1>` tag?

Comment: Please make a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Made it.  http://jsfiddle.net/PNTqb/  Thank you.

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/QnFZT/ ? You just need to clear your floats using `clear: both;`. (Also, they probably shouldn't be inside you `<h1>` tag)

Comment: Guys, you are right about h1 tags probably. But, using clear:both; works fine. But, not in IE. Thanks God I've tested it in 3 browsers right now.

Comment: Still no luck even with clear both:
http://jsfiddle.net/QnFZT/1/

Answer (score 0):

Putting the image in a floating div solved it. See http://jsfiddle.net/dgSCy/1/

But you definitely shouldn't put block elements inside inline elements such as headers...

Comment: But even if he used an inline element as span, it would be turned into block by the float property.

Comment: Putting an image in an additional {floating} div reduces accessibility (please see the question I've started from, it's a logo for SEO and accessibility, not just an image)... Am I right?