# Is a good practice put a canvas into a H1, H2 (..etc) heading for HTML5 semantic?

Tags: html, canvas, semantics, semantic-markup, html-heading

If i am looking for good HTML5 semantic practices, and a optimized code for CEO. Put a canvas in heading, can give poor results?

I mean, this:

```
 <h1>
        <span> Main Title </span>
        <canvas></canvas>
    </h1>

    ... some content... 

    <h2>
        <span> A article </span>
        <canvas></canvas>
    </h2>

    ...
```

Instead this:

```
<h1>
    <span> Main Title </span>
</h1>
<canvas></canvas>

... some content... 

<h2>
    <span> A article </span>
</h2>
<canvas></canvas>

...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is not different to "Should `img` be putted into `h1`?", or even to "Should the word "foobar" be putted into `h1`?" → It depends on your content.

The `canvas` represents content, typically an image. If this image is *part of* the heading, put the `canvas` in the heading. If this image is *described by* the heading, don’t put it in the heading.

Don’t forget to include fallback content, e.g., `<canvas><!-- fallback content --></canvas>`. This fallback content would be part of the heading (for older user-agents, screen readers, search engines, …). If it doesn’t make sense in the heading, `canvas` shouldn’t be there in the first place.

---

Note that the [`canvas` HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/embedded-content-0.html#the-canvas-element) has, what might seem, a relevant paragraph:

> Authors should not use the `canvas` element in a document when a more suitable element is available. For example, it is inappropriate to use a `canvas` element to render a page heading: if the desired presentation of the heading is graphically intense, it should be marked up using appropriate elements (typically `h1`) and then styled using CSS and supporting technologies such as XBL.

But this example assumes that one would use `canvas` *instead* of an appropriate element.

Answer (score 3):

Canvas should be outside of heading.

Comment: Because canvas usually is a bunch of script, not a TITLE, which that's what a heading is for. To Show TITLES...

Comment: +1 Fair enough :)  I guess if the design calls for text over canvas you can always wrap the <h1> and <canvas> in a wrapper <div> and use CSS positioning...

Answer (score 0):

I think this StackOverflow question from 2010 is relevant here:
[Replacing H1 text with a logo image: best method for SEO and accessibility?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665037/replacing-h1-text-with-a-logo-image-best-method-for-seo-and-accessibility)

I also think that if you want to use a canvas element inside <h1> tags etc, you really need to include an alt attribute in the canvas tag to explain what the canvas is showing, and also include the alt attribute text in a span(?) tag within the canvas tag, for those browsers that don't support canvas.

Comment: It is better to avoid error, then make it and try to fix it with alt. Also canvas alt looks like <canvas>text here, visible if canvas is not supported.</canvas>

Comment: I suggested the alt text for accessibility reasons eg people using text-to-speech facilities.