# Why does Safari keep re-loading my logo on every page?

Tags: html, css, image, safari

Just out of curiousity:

Is there something different in the way that Safari handles images compared to other browsers?

I used to serve the logo of my site as a `background-image` from a CSS file so that it doesn't have to be re-loaded on every page (at least that's what I thought).

I recently switched to another approach because it's more in line with what Google prefers and with what people [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665037/replacing-h1-text-with-a-logo-image-best-method-for-seo-and-accessibility) suggest.

```
<h1>
  <a href="http://www.mycompany.com">
    <img src="logo.png" alt="My Company" />
  </a>
</h1>
```

However, when clicking through the pages the logo keeps flickering because Safari seems to be re-loading it on every page. Other browsers such as Chrome and Firefox are fine, though. It seems that they cache the `logo.png` when they first encounter it.

Any idea why this happens or how to prevent it?